# Access PDO::errorCode in CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pdo

I've got a CakePHP application and I'm interested in reacting to a user's attempt to upload a file that's too large for the MySQL packet size.  I'd like to get the MySQL error and then provide an error message to the user based on that.

It looks like CakePHP uses PDO under the hood, but I'm not sure how to access it.  I'd rather borrow CakePHP's PDO connection so that I don't have to create a new PDO connection w/ the username, password, etc, etc (also so I don't have to worry about problems from multiple connections to the same DB, etc).

It looks like there's a PDO class in CakePHP (http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-PDO.html), but I'm not sure how to actually get to it in order to invoke the errorCode() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-DboSource.html#_lastError) is the method you probably need. In your controller after a save operation you can use `$this->SomeModel->getDataSource()->lastError()` to get the error.

Comment: Yes, @ADmad this gets the dataSource object and retrieves the last error that occured. This is the shortest way in Cake but you can also implement a custom save in the Model you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Or.... check this out:

```
if( is_a( $this->SomeModel->getDataSource(), "DboSource") ) {
    $myPDO = $this->SomeModel->getDataSource()->getConnection();
    debug($myPDO.errorCode()); // or whatever...
}
```

Anyways, thanks a ton for your help with this - there was just a couple too many hops in the documentation for me to find this on my own.

(I'm posting this here instead of as a comment to your answer so that it'll stand out better)

Comment: As a 'meta' question for anyone who cares to comment: Should I mark ADmad's answer as correct or this one?  I wouldn't have found this without ADmad's help, but this actually answers the question I posted.  Any advice would be appreciated!